# C++14 auto deduction error: function returns an array

Tags: c++, arrays, auto, c++14

community!
I'm trying to apply new C++14 features and unexpectedly encountered on error while I was attempting to pass the *const char[]* argument to the function given below:

```
 decltype(auto) autofunc( const auto& a)
 {
     cout<<"Hello World\n";
     cout<<a<<endl;

 }


 auto lambd = [](const auto& word){  autofunc(std::forward< decltype(word) > (word));};

int main()
{


 lambd("Goodbye World\n");


    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why,but the compilier's message is that function tries to return an array (why would it do this?). If I change function's return type to *void* It'll be compiled. If I pass an argument of another type(not array) It  will be compiled. What is the problem with arrays?

**Error message**

```
../../untitled6/main.cpp: In instantiation of '<lambda(const auto:3&)> [with auto:3 = char [15]]':
../../untitled6/main.cpp:74:25:   required from here
../../untitled6/main.cpp:68:84: error: no matching function for call to 'autofunc(const char [15])'
  auto lambd = [](const auto& word){  autofunc(std::forward< decltype(word) > (word));};
                                                                                    ^
../../untitled6/main.cpp:68:84: note: candidate is:
../../untitled6/main.cpp:60:17: note: template<class auto:2> decltype(auto) autofunc(const auto:2&)
  decltype(auto) autofunc( const auto& a)
                 ^
../../untitled6/main.cpp:60:17: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../../untitled6/main.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class auto:2> decltype(auto) autofunc(const auto:2&) [with auto:2 = char [15]]':
../../untitled6/main.cpp:68:84:   required from '<lambda(const auto:3&)> [with auto:3 = char [15]]'
../../untitled6/main.cpp:74:25:   required from here
../../untitled6/main.cpp:60:17: error: function returning an array
```

Comment: What is `functor`? What is `f`? What is the exact problem/error message? What version of what compiler are you using?

Comment: @ildjarn,Oh,sorry. *functor* is unnecessary object, I forgot to eliminate it. The compiler I use is G++-4.9. Error message I added to the question.

Comment: You are not allowed to use `auto` in declarations of function parameters. `decltype(auto) autofunc( const auto& a) {...}` is not valid C++14.

Comment: @T.C. I think you're right. But why compiler doesn't prevent  such declaration and  compile it with another types being passed is a question.
BTW: lambda that calls lambda (with auto type deduction for it's arguments) is compiled...

Comment: @GamovCoder It's a GCC extension but not valid C++14. Any behavior beyond that point is undefined.

Comment: `std::forward` is only useful with `T&&` (or `auto&&`) parameters, not `const T&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a GCC bug.

`auto` is not allowed in function parameter declarations in C++14. This syntax is added by the Concepts Lite TS. The [GCC 4.9 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) say that

> G++ supports unconstrained generic functions as specified by §4.1.2
>   and §5.1.1 of N3889: Concepts Lite Specification. Briefly, `auto` may
>   be used as a type-specifier in a parameter declaration of any function
>   declarator in order to introduce an implicit function template
>   parameter, akin to generic lambdas.

N3889 is an early working draft of the concepts TS. The cited section, 5.1.1, reads in part

> A generic function is denoted by function declarator having `auto` or
>   a *concept-name* as part of the *type-specifier* in its
>   *parameter-declaration-clause*. [*Example*:
>
> ```
> auto f(auto x); // Ok
> void sort(Sortable& c); // Ok (assuming Sortable names a concept)
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]
>
> The use of `auto` or a *concept-name* in the
>   *parameter-declaration-clause* shall be interpreted as the use of a *type-parameter* having the same constraints and the named concept. [ *Note*: The exact mechanism for achieving this is unspecified. — *end
>   note* ] [*Example*: The generic function declared below
>
> ```
> auto f(auto x, const Regular& y);
> ```
>
> Is equivalent to the following declaration
>
> ```
> template<typename T1, Regular T2>
> auto f(T1 x, const T2&);
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Note that this transformation is not supposed to affect the return type; it remains `auto` - meaning that it will be deduced.

Given these rules, `autofunc`'s declaration should have been equivalent to

```
template<class T>
decltype(auto) autofunc( const T& a) { /* ... */ }
```

which would have been valid. Instead, it got interpreted as

```
template<class T>
T autofunc( const T& a) { /* ... */ }
```

causing an error since, with all the forwarding you are doing, `T` ends up getting deduced as an array type.

This is particular ironic since GCC 4.9's own notes (cited above) say that

> ```
> // the following two function declarations are equivalent
> auto incr(auto x) { return x++; }
> template <typename T>
> auto incr(T x) { return x++; }
> ```

which is [demonstrably not the case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9335cf0caad2bca) on GCC 4.9.

Answer (score 2):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'func(const char [15])'
  auto lambd = [](const auto& word){  func(word);};
                                               ^
note: candidate is:

template<class auto:1> 
decltype(auto) func(const auto:1&)

decltype(auto) func( const auto& a)
            ^
```

Is the error you're getting. It says the return type is the same as the parameter. That's because you have `decltype(auto)` and the implementation replaces the "func" with:

```
template<class T>
T func(const T& a)
```

instead of:

```
template<class T, class R>
R func(const T& a);
```

I don't have an explanation why it does this.. but the error itself is clear.

This works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

decltype(auto) func(const auto &a)
{
     cout<<"Hello World\n";
     cout<<a<<endl;
}


 auto lambd = [](const auto word){  func(std::forward<decltype(word)>(word));};

int main()
{
    lambd("Goodbye World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

As soon as you make it a `const reference`, it will not work. I still don't know why yet.

**EDIT:**

The only way I can get it working at all is to do:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

decltype(auto) func(const auto &a)
{
     cout<<"Hello World\n";
     cout<<a<<endl;
}


 auto lambd = [](const auto &word){  func(std::forward<decltype(word)>(word));};

int main()
{
    lambd((const char*)"Goodbye World\n");   
    return 0;
}
```

Aka creating a temporary variable for the string and passing that instead.. OR casting the parameter to a pointer to a char array. It seems that it has a hard time telling whether it is a "const char[15]" or "const char*".

Either way, the above will work.

Comment: It's still unclear why this beahavour concerns only arrays, because function behaves this way only if I pass an array. In other case It's compiled...

Comment: Yes as soon as you change *auto&* to *auto* ( doesn't matter where apply this changes to either func or lambd) it's compiled well

Comment: Got it working. Just cast the parameter to a pointer to a char array as a workaround.. OR create a temporary variable for the string and pass that variable as the parameter.

Comment: So the conclusion is  that auto type deduction for arguments for the ordinary functions is not the part of standart and the way g++ behave ( allows the code to be compiled for all the types except arrays ) is a bug of g++.