# Return type deduction in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14

I have just read about new feature named "return type deduction" available in C++14 and I have question about recursion in function of that type. I have learnt that first return in that function must allow deduce return type.

Examples provided by Wiki completely meet that rule.

```
auto Correct(int i) {
  if (i == 1)
    return i;               // return type deduced as int
  else
    return Correct(i-1)+i;  // ok to call it now
}

auto Wrong(int i) {
  if (i != 1)
    return Wrong(i-1)+i;  // Too soon to call this. No prior return statement.
  else
    return i;             // return type deduced as int
}
```

My question is:
Why when I changed `Wrong(int i)` to `Wrong(auto i)`, `Wrong` function started to compile? What is hidding behind this small change?

Comment: Basically, you made `Wrong` into a function template.

Comment: `auto` as a parameter in a regular function is a GCC extension, not standard C++14.

Comment: [doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d54be4e8410c0a7f)

Comment: And if the `auto i` is changed to a regular template function (`template <typename T> auto Wrong(T i)`), it gets rejected again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in GCC's implementation of its extension to C++14's `auto`. Here is a program that appears to be intended to work:

```
auto f(auto i) {
  return "";
}

int main() {
  const char *s = f(1);
  return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work, it fails with "error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’" because GCC determines, for some reason, that the return type must be the same as the parameter type.

That same bug can make code that's meant to be rejected, such as what's in your question, compile without problems.

Of course, this bug doesn't affect conformance, because no valid C++14 program can use `auto` parameters outside of lambdas.

It happens to have been reported about a week ago to the GCC developers as [bug #64969](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64969), as a result of [another question on SO about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380494/c14-auto-deduction-error-function-returns-an-array/28383834).

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571592/function-returning-auto-with-auto-parameter-munmap-chunk-invalid-pointer) (to your answer, not this question.)

Comment: @remyabel Thanks. I'm also looking through bug reports, but I'm having trouble finding anything there.

Comment: If you're willing to sift through the concepts TS, you could probably determine if GCC's behavior is buggy or "conforming". They're called "Abbreviated Function Templates" now.

Comment: @remyabel The only thing I can find in N4333 is that function parameter `auto` types get replaced by invented template parameters. I don't see any mention of `auto` being changed outside of function parameters. But it doesn't help that there isn't any example in there combining `auto` parameters with an `auto` return type.

Comment: GCC's behavior is not conforming to [N4377 Programming Languages — C++ Extensions for Concepts (the PDTS)](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4377.pdf) [dcl.funct]: the declaration `auto foo(auto bar)` is equivalent to `template<typename T> auto foo(T bar)`. Placeholders in the return type are not affected.

Comment: @Casey Agreed, but GCC doesn't claim to implement that, and there is a lot in N4377 that GCC doesn't implement at all, not just incorrectly.

Comment: @hvd True, [the GCC 4.9 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) specify the extension conforms to [the earlier Concepts draft N3889](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3889.pdf). The specification for *generic functions* therein is similar to that of  *abbreviated function templates* in N4377. The 4.9 release notes include the example "`auto incr(auto x) { return x++; }` [is equivalent to] `template <typename T>
auto incr(T x) { return x++; }`" that demonstrates the cited behavior does not conform to either spec.

Comment: @Casey Right. And that's exactly what T.C. pointed out in the bug report. :)